# About Android Studio 0.5 'sourceSets'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm update the Android Studio to version 0.5, but the 'build.gradle' file has some warning.

Like this: 'main' in 'build' cannot be applied to ...

And in Android Studio's project panel,the source file show some warning, visit image https://raw.github.com/MarkMjw/xiangmao.github.io/master/test.png

The code：

```
sourceSets {
    main{
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    ...
}
```

My project created by Eclipse, and some members are still use Eclipse, but the others are use Android Studio, so I don't change directory structure to Gradle style.

I should be how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's fine to use Eclipse directory structure, as long as the srcDirs point to the right places. In a simple project, what you have is fine. A message like "cannot be applied to" means there is a mismatch between types, which could happen if there is a library that couldn't be read or wasn't included properly. We can't tell without knowing more about your project or what the specific warnings/errors are.

Comment: Thank you to help me, [the screenshots](https://raw.github.com/MarkMjw/xiangmao.github.io/master/screen.png),I don't know what's meaning of the red icon on the source file(.java).Before updating the version,this icon is not exist.I think some errors in 'build.grdle' in my project, however,my project can run normally.

Comment: Can you please include the full warning messages when you open your project? I don't understand your description.

Comment: Same problem on intellij 13.1.2 and gradle for android 0.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66758. We're trying to get a patch release for 0.5.0 put together to fix this among other issues.

According to the bug report, users have been able to work around it by removing the line:

```
resources.srcDirs = ['src']
```

I haven't tried it personally, but you might want to see if it works for you.

Comment: I can confirm that removing this line fixed it. Thanks! It's still showing the warning, but the files show up correctly again.

Comment: Thanks, the bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66758 the first issue is still showing : main tag in 'build.gradle' is highlighted as warning with message "'main' in 'build' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure<java.util.ArrayList>)'". The second issue has been solved in android studio 0.5.1.

Comment: The syntax highlighting and error detection for build files isn't finished yet.